# ASP.NET WinForms C# - How to update Label with value edited in JQGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

I have a page with JQGrid bound to SqlDataSource1 and Label bound to SqlDataSource2. Both SqlDataSources are selecting from the same table, the first one selects all records and the second one returns only one record which is SelectedRow in JQGrid. Label's Text property is bound to value of one field from that record. All is working fine, but when I click on Edit button in JQGrid and edit selected record in opened dialog, then after dialog is closed, I want to update edited value in my Label too. But JQGrid event RowEdited is not causing postback. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the RowEdited event as part of the edit row documentation but there would be other events you could call on to update your label.

What jumped out at me was the aftersavefunction call where you could set the value without having to call the server to update your label.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow

If you want to use Form Editing then you could tie into the `afterComplete` function of the call to update your label. This is especially nice as you can get a positive confirmation your edit was saved as part of the `afterComplete` function before making the change to the label.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing

Comment: Cool, but wait, how are you planning on doing a postback via a server side event?

Comment: It is my main issue. I don't know how to do that. I would be update Label on client side, but I dont know an event which is fired after edit dialog is closed.

Comment: Well, perhaps I am misunderstanding, but there is no way to trigger an update from a server side event, the client must initiate the call.  I think you will find afterComplete will meet your needs to trigger an update of the Label after a save event has occurred and you have returned a positive save confirmation response to the function.

Comment: Yes I found it too, but I am weak at javascript. Can you please write some super easy example of javascript function for that event? I only need to get value of one field from edited row by his name.

Comment: It's hard to write from thin air, if you post up your code where you setup your grid and the label elements it might be doable.  You would probably easily find some examples of a the `afterComplete` function in action as well.

Comment: I am hard googling whole day. afterComplete event looks very promising. I'll continue with my searching. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Hopefully it puts you on the right track, it sounds like exactly what you need.  Please mark correct if this is the solution. Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, I think afterComplete event is great and I found good examples how to use it. Only one thing is wrong for me. Version of JQGrid I am using don't have client side event afterComplete. I am very sad. Maybe LoadComplete client side event is what I am looking for.

Comment: Probably a great reason to have a hard look at the latest version then. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Mark I solve this and here is example of javacript (jquery) function I'm using to handle LoadComplete client side event of JQGrid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadComplete(data) {
        if (data == null) return;
        var selectedRowId = '<%=(Session["SelectedRow"] == null)?string.Empty:Session["SelectedRow"].ToString()%>';
        if (selectedRowId == '') return;
        var rows = $.map(data.rows, function (value) {
            return (value.id == selectedRowId) ? value : null;
        });
        var selectedRow = rows[0];
        var id = selectedRow.cell[0];
        var name = selectedRow.cell[1];
        var surname = selectedRow.cell[2];
        $('#<%= this.lblName.ClientID %>').html(name);
        $('#<%= this.lblSurname.ClientID %>').html(surname);
    }
</script>
```